Paper on PTSD and trauma
I'm looking for a paper on PTSD  research.
Last year, 2023, I found this paper I'm having trouble finding today. I believe the main author had a masculine name. The paper was a survey of various factors contributing to the development of PTSD. One idea evaluated was intensity of a trauma vs. likelihood of developing PTSD vs. pre-existing psychological conditions. Claimed those who developed PTSD typically had a pre-existing issue, less so people without such conditions even under intense stress. The paper also broke up associated traumas into two categories. As I recall, the first category was a set of a handful of stressors known to cause PTSD, e.g. violent assault, life threatening experiences of danger to oneself or others nearby, natural disasters, etc. These were classical traumas associated with PTSD. The paper also addressed less severe stressors that nonetheless had similar impacts in terms of engendering PTSD, divorce, losing a job, etc. There may have also been reference to some resistance factor to development of PTSD.
Anyone know how I can search for this paper? Google is giving me some trouble. I think I might not have the right technical vocabulary to do the search.
Update: Just remembered another part of the paper. There was some research on reports of PTSD symptoms resulting from witnessing 9/11 and/or its aftermath on tv for some people.

It would help if you could share the keyword combinations you tried and the search engine you used

I think the key word you are looking for is 'comorbidity'. Using the search string 'PTSD + trauma + comorbidity' in Google Scholar gave the following two oft-cited papers as the top two hits, both of which could be of help to you. I'll share the papers and links below, since a search under my Google account may yield different results than yours:

Brady Posttraumatic stress disorder and comorbidity: recognizing the many faces of PTSD. J Clin Psych (1997); 58;S8: 12-5
Brady et al. Comorbidity of psychiatric disorders and posttraumatic stress disorder. J Clin Psychiatry (2000); 61(S7):22-32

